# How to transpose a dataframe in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, transpose

I have the following dataframe:

```
+--------------------+---+---+-----+----+--------+----+
|                  ak| 1 | 2 |  3  | 4  |   5    |  6 |
+--------------------+---+---+-----+----+--------+----+
|8dce120638dbdf438   |  2|  1|    0|   0|       0|   0|
|3fd28484316249e95   |  1|  0|    3|   1|       4|   5|
|3636b43f64db33889   |  9|  3|    3|   4|      18|  11|
+--------------------+---+---+-----+----+--------+----+
```

and I want transpose it to the following:

```
ak                 depth    user_count
8dce120638dbdf438    1       2
8dce120638dbdf438    2       1
8dce120638dbdf438    3       0
8dce120638dbdf438    4       0
8dce120638dbdf438    5       0
8dce120638dbdf438    6       0
3fd28484316249e95    1       1
3fd28484316249e95    2       0
3fd28484316249e95    3       3
3fd28484316249e95    4       1
3fd28484316249e95    5       4
3fd28484316249e95    6       5
3fd28484316249e95    1       9
3fd28484316249e95    2       3
3fd28484316249e95    3       3
3fd28484316249e95    4       4
3fd28484316249e95    5       18
3fd28484316249e95    6       11
```

How to do it in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar approach to @Ramesh Maharjan's, but without the use of UDFs - instead, using Spark's built-in `array` and `struct` functions to construct a similar array that can be exploded:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

// per column name, create a struct (similar to a tuple) of the column name and value:
def arrayItem(name: String) = struct(lit(name) cast IntegerType as "depth", $"$name" as "user_count")

// create an array of these per column, explode it and select the relevant columns:
df.withColumn("tmp", explode(array(df.columns.tail.map(arrayItem): _*)))
  .select($"ak", $"tmp.depth", $"tmp.user_count")
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution seems straight forward to collect the values with column names into an array form, then use explode function to separate each element of array into separate rows, then finally separate the key and value to separate columns.

Summarizing the above explanation into code with explanation are as given below

```
val columns = df.columns.tail   //selecting columns to be changed to rows

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
//defining udf for zipping the column names with value and returning as array of column names zipped with column values
def zipUdf = udf((cols: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String], vals: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => cols.zip(vals))

df.select(col("ak"), zipUdf(lit(columns), array(columns.map(col): _*)).as("depth"))   //calling udf function above
    .withColumn("depth", explode(col("depth")))                                       //exploding the array column to be on separate rows
    .select(col("ak"), col("depth._1").as("depth"), col("depth._2").as("user_count")) //selecting columns as required in output
  .show(false)
```

You should have the following output

```
+-----------------+-----+----------+
|ak               |depth|user_count|
+-----------------+-----+----------+
|8dce120638dbdf438|1    |2         |
|8dce120638dbdf438|2    |1         |
|8dce120638dbdf438|3    |0         |
|8dce120638dbdf438|4    |0         |
|8dce120638dbdf438|5    |0         |
|8dce120638dbdf438|6    |0         |
|3fd28484316249e95|1    |1         |
|3fd28484316249e95|2    |0         |
|3fd28484316249e95|3    |3         |
|3fd28484316249e95|4    |1         |
|3fd28484316249e95|5    |4         |
|3fd28484316249e95|6    |5         |
|3636b43f64db33889|1    |9         |
|3636b43f64db33889|2    |3         |
|3636b43f64db33889|3    |3         |
|3636b43f64db33889|4    |4         |
|3636b43f64db33889|5    |18        |
|3636b43f64db33889|6    |11        |
+-----------------+-----+----------+
```